keycloak import realm with client
Why when I import realm.json by docker compose command, my clients dosen't come? when I import by the keycloak interface my clients come?
I need to import by docker compose command.
Follow my file:
version: '3.8'

services:   postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - keycloak-network

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.1
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realm.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
      - ./keycloak/users.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/users.json
    command: ["start-dev", "--import-realm"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - keycloak-network

volumes:   postgres_data:

networks:   keycloak-network:

I tried import by docker compose, but I couldn't. I expect can do it

Add this ARG to the command:
-Dkeycloak.import=/opt/keycloak/data/import/

